# How to take random samples for H2O data frame in R?

Tags: h2o

I have a h2o data table with 40 columns and 1 million rows. I want do a random selection of 0.3 million rows without replacement. The H2o.sample function i looked online gives the error (I've already start h2o cluster)

```
Error: could not find function "h2o.sample"
```

Is there any other way i can do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no `h2o.sample()` function (maybe there was in a very old version of H2O?).  You can use the `h2o.splitFrame()` function to split your frame into pieces.  This also serves as a way to take a random subset of your data frame (without replacement).  The function will actually create two (or more) pieces of your data, so if you want just the 30%, here is an example in R using iris to get a ~30% random sample of the rows:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

hf <- as.h2o(iris)
ss <- h2o.splitFrame(hf, ratios = c(0.3), seed = 1)
sub_hf <- ss[[1]]   # will contain 30% of the rows
```

Note that for scalability reasons, `h2o.splitFrame()` uses "approximate splitting" which means that you won't necessarily get exactly 30% of the rows.  However, the expected value is 30%, and it will closer to the desired percentage when your data is bigger.  The iris is a tiny 150 row dataset, so there is more variance.